# How can I find the size of the memory referenced by a pointer?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, pointers

GetMem allows you to allocate a buffer of arbitrary size.  Somewhere, the size information is retained by the memory manager, because you don't need to tell it how big the buffer is when you pass the pointer to FreeMem.

Is that information for internal use only, or is there any way to retrieve the size of the buffer pointed to by a pointer?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969007/is-it-possible-to-get-the-size-of-the-type-that-a-pointer-points-to-in-delphi-7/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would seem that the size of a block referenced by a pointer returned by **GetMem()** must be available from somewhere, given that **FreeMem()** does not require that you identify the size of memory to be freed - the *system* must be able to determine that, so why not the application developer?

But, as others have said, the precise details of the memory management involved are NOT defined by the system per se.... Delphi has always had a replaceable memory manager architecture, and the "interface" defined for compatible memory managers does not require that they provide this information for an arbitrary pointer.

The default memory manager will maintain the necessary information in whatever way suits it, but some other memory manager will almost certainly use an entirely different, if superficially similar, mechanism, so even if you hack a solution based on intimate knowledge of one memory manager, if you change the memory manager (or if it is changed for you, e.g. by a change in thesystem defined, memory manager which you perhaps are using by default, as occurred between Delphi 2005 and 2006, for example) then your solution will almost certainly break.

In general, it's not an unreasonable assumption on the part of the RTL/memory manager that the application should already know how big a piece of memory a **GetMem()** allocated pointer refers to, given that the application asked for it in the first place!  :)

And if your application *did NOT* allocate the pointer then your application's memory manager has absolutely no way of knowing how big the block it references may be.  It may be a pointer into the *middle* of some larger block, for example - only the source of the pointer can possibly know how it relates to the memory it references!

But, if your application really does need to maintain such information about it's *own* pointers, then it could of course easily devise a means to achieve this with a simple singleton class or function library through which **GetMem()**/**FreeMem()** requests are routed, to maintain a record of the associated requested size for each current allocated pointer.  Such a mechanism could then of course easily expose this information as required, entirely reliably and independently of whatever memory manager is in use.

This may in face be the only option if an "*accurate*" record is required , as a given memory manager implementation may allocate a larger block of memory for a given size of data than is actually requested.  I do not know if any memory manager does in fact do this, but it could do so in theory, for efficiency sake.

Answer (score 5):

It is for internal use as it depends on the MemoryManager used. BTW, that's why you need to use the pair GetMem/FreeMem from the same MemoryManager; there is no canonical way of knowing how the memory has been reserved.
In Delphi, if you look at FastMM4, you can see that the memory is allocated in small, medium or large blocks:
 the **small blocks** are allocated in pools of fixed size blocks (block size is defined at the pool level in the block type)

```
  TSmallBlockType = packed record
    {True = Block type is locked}
    BlockTypeLocked: Boolean;
    {Bitmap indicating which of the first 8 medium block groups contain blocks
     of a suitable size for a block pool.}
    AllowedGroupsForBlockPoolBitmap: byte;
    {The block size for this block type}
    BlockSize: Word;
```

the **medium blocks** are also allocated in pools but have a variable size

```
  {Medium block layout:
   Offset: -8 = Previous Block Size (only if the previous block is free)
   Offset: -4 = This block size and flags
   Offset: 0 = User data / Previous Free Block (if this block is free)
   Offset: 4 = Next Free Block (if this block is free)
   Offset: BlockSize - 8 = Size of this block (if this block is free)
   Offset: BlockSize - 4 = Size of the next block and flags

  {Get the block header}
  LBlockHeader := PCardinal(Cardinal(APointer) - BlockHeaderSize)^;
  {Get the medium block size}
  LBlockSize := LBlockHeader and DropMediumAndLargeFlagsMask;
```

the **large blocks** are allocated individually with the required size

```
  TLargeBlockHeader = packed record
    {Points to the previous and next large blocks. This circular linked
     list is used to track memory leaks on program shutdown.}
    PreviousLargeBlockHeader: PLargeBlockHeader;
    NextLargeBlockHeader: PLargeBlockHeader;
    {The user allocated size of the Large block}
    UserAllocatedSize: Cardinal;
    {The size of this block plus the flags}
    BlockSizeAndFlags: Cardinal;
  end;
```

Comment: I thought ansistring depended on the size being prefixed. It seems there is no uniform way to load the blocksize to do this, how does this work? Is there a size in the allocation now?

Comment: AnsiString has the *length* prefixed, but that's because the RTL adds an extra 4 bytes to before it calls `GetMem`. (Plus another 4 for the reference count, and as of Delphi 2009, 2 for the code page, and 2 for the element size.) When you lengthen a string, the RTL calls `ReallocMem`, which allows the memory manager to choose whether to inflate the allocation in-place or to allocate a new block (with a new address). It has been that way forever; AnsiStrings don't use the memory manager's internal bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that information for internal use only, or is there any way to retrieve the size of the buffer pointed to by a pointer?

Do these two `alternatives' contradict each other?

It's for internal use only.

Comment: What I meant is, is that information hidden from the developer because it's for internal use only, or is there a way to get at it?

Comment: What *I* meant that even if the information is for internal use, you still may have a way to get it.  Or may not.  The true statement is that *this information is for internal use only*.  Everything else doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is some information before the allocated area to store meta information. This means, each time you allocate a piece of memory, a bigger piece is allocated and the first bytes are used for meta information. The returned pointer is to the block following this meta information.

I can imagine that the format is changed with an other version of the memory manager so don't count on this.

Answer (score 0):

That information is for internal use only.

Note that memory managers doesn't need to store the size as part of the memory returned, many memory managers will store it in an internal table and use the memory address of the start of the chunk given out as a lookup key in that table.